# Ajax, CSRF and DELETE

Tags: django, django-csrf

I use the `getCookie` function from the [`django` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) to get the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` value.

I have the following ajax call:

```
var url = reverse_removeprofile.replace(/deadbeef/, key);
$.ajax({
    type:          "DELETE",
    url:           url,
    data:          "csrfmiddlewaretoken=" + getCookie("csrftoken"),
    success:       function() { ... },
});
```

When this code gets executed then `django` raises a 403 exception telling me that the CSRF verification failed. However, if I change the `type` from `DELETE` to `POST` then `django` is happy about it and doesn't complain at all.

I was not really able to find something useful in Google about this, but I've found this (now closed and fixed) ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15258

If I understand it correctly then this issue has been fixed in the 1.4 milestone. I use django 1.4 but still I cannot verify the CSRF token with a `DELETE` request.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This appears to be a jQuery bug, caused by some confusion as to whether DELETE data should be attached to the URL (like a GET request) or the request body (like a POST)

See [this bug report](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11586).

You can probably get around this by using the alternative CSRF method for AJAX calls, setting an `X-CSRFToken` header on the request. Try changing your AJAX call to look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie("csrftoken"));
    },
    success: function() { ... },
});
```

Comment: thank's a lot! This solved the problem :) and there I was blaming the csrf-middleware stuff.

Comment: Wow. I never would have figured that out on my own. Thanks.

Comment: I just faced this issue in 2019. The solution still works! I was also adding the csrftoken in the 'data' attribute of the AJAX call, but I guess, this is not attached in the request when the 'DELETE' method is being used, so the backend never receives the token.

Comment: This is still an issue in 2020. If you use `$.ajax` for `POST` and for `DELETE` you must pass the csrf this way. Also, pycharm does not recognize that `beforeSend` is being used. It suggests remove unused property, even though it is required.

Answer (score 1):

**Please note, when it comes to `DELETE` requests DJango does not check for `csrfmiddlewaretoken` in the request body. Rather it looks for `X-CSRFToken` header**

Coming to working of DJango CSRFMiddleware you can see the source code of `django > middleware > csrf.py > CsrfViewMiddleware` in which it is very clear that DJango does not scan for `csrfmiddlewaretoken` in request body if the request is of `DELETE` type:

```
        # Check non-cookie token for match.
        request_csrf_token = ""
        if request.method == "POST":
            try:
                request_csrf_token = request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '')
            except OSError:
                # Handle a broken connection before we've completed reading
                # the POST data. process_view shouldn't raise any
                # exceptions, so we'll ignore and serve the user a 403
                # (assuming they're still listening, which they probably
                # aren't because of the error).
                pass

        if request_csrf_token == "":
            # Fall back to X-CSRFToken, to make things easier for AJAX,
            # and possible for PUT/DELETE.
            request_csrf_token = request.META.get(settings.CSRF_HEADER_NAME, '')
```